# Entity Framework 6 / MVC5 - passing incomplete entity and additional arguments to Create method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

My application has a Create view in which users are asked to input certain values for the view's entity, and other values come from non-inputs (the current user's username, the current user's office within the organisation and the region the office is in). I've amended the Create method as follows:

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include="User input value1,value2,value3")] MyEntity myentity,
     string Username, int OfficeId, int RegionId)
```

Then in the method immediately before if (ModelState.IsValid) is tested:

```
myentity.OfficeID = OfficeId;
myentity.RegionID = RegionId;
myentity.UserID = Username";
myentity.DateEntered = DateTime.Now();
```

The record is inserted into the database as intended, but my question is whether this is how I should be going about it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you have parameters for `Username`, `OfficeId` and `RegionId` if _"other values come from non-inputs"_? Or do you mean hidden inputs in which case why send the values to the client and post them back? (just get them in the POST method rather than the GET method)

Comment: Hi Stephen, I'm inserting a new record so the values aren't being sent in the first place. A user logs in and enters some data, and along with the data values from his/her login make up part of the record to be inserted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might run in to some problems if the fields you're setting explicitly have validation annotations. For instance, if `OfficeId` is a required field on your model, then `ModelState` will have an error since it was not present when the validation happened. If that's the case, I would use a separate viewmodel for the data you want to collect from the user, and then construct your domain model from that and the additional values. If those fields don't have validation annotations then I don't see any reason why the way you're doing it wouldn't work.